# Washer "wall outlet must not be located behind dryer."

Tags: electrical, dryer, washing-machine, clothes-washer

Recently I noticed a washing machine manual which says "Wall outlet must not be located behind dryer." A [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&btnG=Search&q=%22wall%20outlet%20must%20not%20be%20located%20behind%20dryer%22) reveals this is pretty common, but what's the reason for it?

I understand that the washer needs "regular" 120V AC and not 220V like you sometimes find behind a dryer, but why would a regular outlet box that happens to be behind an adjacent dryer (i.e. not too far away for cord length to be an issue), be unacceptable?

Comment: Man, I have serious issues then - I swapped my washer and dryer completely.

Comment: I think it's related to access. You want to be able to pull the plug quickly without having to hire a few strong men to move the dryer.

Comment: Not sure what the clearance requirements are for a dryer, but it could have to do with the cord potentially encroaching on this zone. It could also have to do with the potential for the cord to be in contact with the dryer vent.

Comment: @ratchetfreak If it takes a few men to move the dryer, then by definition they aren't very strong...

Comment: Receptacles in laundry areas are quite often at the 4' mark to keep them above the washer *and* dryer.  Realistically the washer is always the heavier appliance, if they were worried about easy disconnect access they would have said "don't put anything in front of the receptacle" not just the dryer.

Comment: @JeffMeden Really good point, especially in your second sentence.  Lacking any specific instruction otherwise even when it's present and referring to the dryer, the instructions indicate it'd be fine to have the receptacle behind the washer, like right behind where the cord comes out of the machine.

Comment: @Tester101 dryer vents should never pass 160F (if it does you have a bigger problem) and UL (or similarly rated) appliance cords start at 194F(90C) operating ceiling so while it is valid to want to keep them apart, there should realistically never be a consequence of having an appliance cord directly contacting the vent.

Answer (score 1):

Some of those are up/down washer/dryer combos, and the dryer is actually mounted to the wall in a semi-permanent fashion. As such, you can't have the washer plugged in behind the dryer because it is no longer in a freely accessible receptacle, electrically the washer is sort of permanently installed itself (which is a bad idea in general.)  The ones that aren't, I suspect, are guilty of a lazy GE washer manual writer.  It is not a code requirement of any sort.

*edited with more detail

Comment: The one I was looking at was a standalone washer that stands next to a dryer.

Comment: I'm gonna have to go with the "Lazy GE washer manual writer" portion of this answer explains your specific scenario while the rest of the answer is why it might ever be there in the first place.